# INT_PTR in 64 bit conversion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, 32bit-64bit

I am converting a large project of multiple c++ applications from 32 bit MFC to 64 bit.  These applications will be required to be compiled in both 32 and 64 bit for the forseeable future.

I've run across these types INT_PTR and UINT_PTR.  I have two questions.

1. Is it considered best practice to use these types as a "default" type for general integer purposes, such as loop counters, etc?
2. I understand that the size of these types are related to the pointer size of the environment you are compiling for, but it seems confusing to use them for general purpose integer.  For example for (INT_PTR i = 0; i<10; i++) ... ;  i isn't a pointer or pointer related, so the name of the type is confusing to me.  Are there better predefines to be used in this situation or should I make my own?

My compiler is VS2010.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with basic types for most things? The only things to worry about in 32 and 64 bit environments is differences when reading/writing binary and handling of certain values. If you REQUIRE a certain sized field use the appropriate (int32_t, uint64_t, etc...) or define your own for both environments.

Comment: My main concern is speed.  There are certain time critical functions that need to be as efficient as possible.  My understanding is it's better to use 64 bit integers for general purpose in a 64 bit environment.  Also we often get 64 bit values from built in functions.  For example: MyFunc(strlen(my_string));  In 64 bit, my options are either cast the result of strlen to an 32 bit value or to change MyFunc to take a size_t or UINT_PTR as a parameter.

Comment: If you are concerned about speed, have you actually **profiled** the application? If you haven't, don't worry. A quality that matters to customers is "*Fast enough"*. Customers usually don't care about *"As fast as possible"*. If you really need to speed up the application, consider offloading intensive computations to any of the vector units (e.g. SSE/AVX, GPU).

Answer (score 3):

`INT_PTR` and similar have a very specific use-case: They model a data type that is large enough and with appropriate alignment requirements to hold an integer or a pointer type. It is used in situations where a method has parameters or a return type that is either an integral data type or a pointer (like [`GetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585.aspx)).

For loops there is no generic advice other than this: Use the most appropriate type. If your loop index is used to index into a container, make it a `size_t`. If your loop index is an integer that runs across all values in between `x` and `y`, use the type of `x` and `y`, or one that is compatible with both. An `INT_PTR` is not really an appropriate loop index data type.

Comment: size_t has one huge drawback: backwards loops. Writing something like (size_t i = container.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) results in an endless loop or most probably in a crash. It's also of note that MFC containers use INT_PTR as type for index and length (as opposed to an unsigned type) and my guess is that this backwards loop issue is the reason for it.

Comment: @nar This is not specific to `size_t`. You can provoke this bug whenever you apply a construct that works for signed integers to unsigned integers. The lesson here is not: Avoid `size_t`. The lesson is: Avoid raw loops whenever possible.

Comment: @Ilnspectable If course it would be better to void raw loops, but sometimes you just can't reasonably. And imo more importantly: Analyzing and rewriting every loop is a huge task. I'm currently working on migrating an an MFC application that started 25 years ago and has several million lines of code. If you start out with over 5000 warnings and several thousand issues without warnings you don't want to spend the time to rewrite every for loop. Especially when a lot of the code is from an era where raw loops were the only option, from an era that didn't even have templates.

Comment: @nar None of that is meaningful in this context. I was commenting on the statement, that `size_t` were to have *"one huge drawback"*. And that's simply not true. It's incorrect code that is to blame here, like your example, that doesn't just fail due to signedness conflicts, but also on empty containers. Both of which can be *easily* fixed: `for (size_t i = container.size(); i > 0; --i) { /* Operate on element at index (i - 1) */ }`. There, fixed two bugs. Where is that *"huge drawback"* now?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/ "Windows Data Types"

You might be a bit confused about the purpose for this type.  It's there to ensure that if you cast a pointer to an int (which you probably shouldn't do anyway) you have an int type that fits.  Windows is a bit odd in that (if memory serves) int is still 32 bits when compiling for 64 bits.  If you need an int of a specific size I'd use the exact width types (in stdint.h)

Comment: `int` is 32 bits on 64-bit Linux, 64-bit Macintosh, and 64-bit BSD as well.

Comment: Good to know I thought these had used the more natural 64 bit size for ints.

Comment: Unfortunately INT_PTR is also the type of index and length operations of MFC containers, so something like for (int i = 0; i < container.GetSize(); ++i) will result in an endless loop or most probably a crash if the container has more elements than an int can represent.

Answer (score 0):

If your loop is not related to pointers (that is, it is not used as an index of an array or a vector or anything like that), use `int` whenever a generic integer type is required. It's a good thing to make sure your code doesn't depend on size of `int` (although for MS VS `int` is 32 bit for both platforms).

Use `size_t`, `vector<...>::size_type` or other appropriate type for index-related loops.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the datatype "intptr_t". It's a platform specific datatype. It holds 4 byte values in 32 bit platform while 8 byte values in 64 bit platform.